# BigQuery: GROUP BY clause for QUANTILES

Tags: google-bigquery

Based on the bigquery query reference, currently Quantiles do not allow any kind of grouping by another column. I am mainly interested in getting **medians grouped by a certain column**. The only work around I see right now is to generate a quantile query per distinct group member where the group member is a condition in the where clause.

For example I use the below query for every distinct row in column-y if I want to get the desired result.

```
SELECT QUANTILE( <column-x>, 1001)
FROM <table>
WHERE 
    <column-y> == <each distinct row in column-y>
```

1. Does the big query team plan on having some functionality to allow grouping on quantiles in the future?
2. Is there a better way to get what I am trying to get here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are efficient algorithms to compute quantiles they are somewhat memory intensive  - trying to do multiple quantile calculations in a single query gets expensive.

1. There are plans to improve QUANTILES, but I don't know what the timeline is.
2. Do you need median? Can you filter outliers and do an average of the remainder?

Comment: I am mainly interested in medians. But 99th and 99.9th percentile would be nice to have. I cannot filter out the outliers either. So it seems like I will have to run separate queries to get the desired result. This will be a nice feature to add to big query in the future though. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 7):

With the recently announced percentile_cont() window function you can get medians.

Look at the example in the announcement blog post:

http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/06/google-bigquery-bigger-faster-smarter-analytics-functions.html

```
SELECT MAX(median) AS median, room FROM (
  SELECT percentile_cont(0.5) OVER (PARTITION BY room ORDER BY data) AS median, room
  FROM [io_sensor_data.moscone_io13]
  WHERE sensortype='temperature'
)
GROUP BY room
```

Comment: Hi @felipe-hoffa, you have bug in query reference https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#percentile_cont, because query there returns 1 and not 4

Answer (score 0):

If your per-group size is fixed, you may be able to hack it using combination of `order`, `nest` and `nth`. For instance, if there are 9 distinct values of `f2` per value of `f1`, for median:

```
select f1,nth(5,f2) within record from (
  select f1,nest(f2) f2 from (
    select f1, f2 from table
    group by f1,f2
    order by f2
  ) group by f1
);
```

Not sure if the sorted order in subquery is guaranteed to survive the second `group`, but it worked in a simple test I tried.